# Why did Count Dooku stop being a Jedi?

Tags: star-wars, attack-of-the-clones

At the beginning of *Star Wars: Episode II* when Padme is talking with Yoda, Mace Windu, etc., she claims to believe that Count Dooku was behind the assassination attempt; however, Windu defends Dooku in saying that it's not in his character and that he was once a Jedi.

> PADME: I think that Count Dooku was behind it.
> MUNDI: He's a political idealist, not a murderer.
> WINDU: You know m'lady Count Dooku was once a Jedi. He couldn't assassinate anyone, it's not in his nature.

Why did Dooku 'resign' from being a Jedi?

Comment: Do you want the Canon version, or the Legends version? Dooku's pages on Wookieepedia provide both. In both cases, Dooku got tired of the Republic and the Jedi becoming more and more corrupt and shortsighted but the details differ considerably between the two versions.

Comment: @SpaceWolf1701 Canon would be great if it's fleshed out. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

In the canon novel Star Wars: Legacy of the Jedi, it is explained the story of Lorian Nod and Count Dooku, friends during their Jedi days. I'd recommend reading it and you'll find your answer. Dooku had lost faith and also been talking to Sidious and Lorian confronted him; the match essentially came to a draw and the story takes it into the Clone Wars as well.

Comment: You should [edit] this to include supporting quotes instead of saying I recommend you read it to find the answer. Also note that quality over quantity win out here. You don't have to answer anything and everything. Take some time to write out a nice quality answer with supporting evidence rather than just taking 30 seconds to answer a question and then moving on to answer the next a minute later.